# watchOS: Can I start a system workout?

Tags: ios, healthkit, watchos-3

I'd like to have watchOS or iOS start a particular `HKWorkoutConfiguration` when I press a button in my app.

However, I'd prefer to launch the watchOS' Workout app, rather than my own watchOS app. (The Workouts app has really great timers, lock UI, music controls in watchOS 4, etc -- and I'm not interested in trying to copy all of that.)

Is that possible? Or, to support starting a workout from my app, do I have to create my own workout UI on watchOS?